# C# Async UDP Server - How to Pass Socket to Callback

Tags: c#, asynchronous, server, udp

I'm trying to write an async udp server and im having difficulty trying to understand how some of the stuff works.
On this code, the program stops on the method ClientConnected(), saying that asyncResult.asyncstate as socket is null, so how do i pass the sender's socket to the callback?

```
class UDPServer
{
byte[] byteData;
int bufferSize;

public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

Socket serverSocket;
IPEndPoint localIPEP;
EndPoint sender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

IPEndPoint[,] playerList = new IPEndPoint[5000, 2]; // 5000 possible player lobbies, each with 2 player ip addresses and ports
int playerListIndex = 0; // we start filling up the lobbies from 0

bool waitingForSecondClient;

public UDPServer(IPEndPoint serverIpEndPoint)
{
    bufferSize = 1024;
    byteData = new byte[1024];


    localIPEP = serverIpEndPoint;
    serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,SocketType.Dgram,ProtocolType.Udp);

    serverSocket.Bind(localIPEP);

    Console.WriteLine("Server setup complete.");
}

public void GetConnection()
{
    while (true)
    {
        allDone.Reset();
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for new client.");
        serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref sender, ClientConnected, sender);
        allDone.WaitOne();
    }
}

public void ClientConnected(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
{
    allDone.Set();

    byte[] data = new byte[1024];
    data = byteData;
    byteData = null;
    Socket clientSocket = asyncResult.AsyncState as Socket;
    EndPoint remote = clientSocket.LocalEndPoint;
    int bytesReceived = serverSocket.EndReceiveFrom(asyncResult, ref remote);
    string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesReceived);
    remote = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref remote, ClientConnected, remote);


    Console.WriteLine("-------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Received bytes of data: " + bytesReceived);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------");
    Console.WriteLine("Received string: " + message);
    Console.WriteLine("-------------");

    if (message.Equals("New client"))
    {
        Send(clientSocket, "Hello");
    }
```

Comment: Unrelated: Some people probably will suggest using TPL (async/await) instead. Is that an option for you?

Comment: instead of..? sorry im kinda new with this

Comment: Instead of legacy async (BeginXXX, EndXXX).

Comment: will look into it i guess

Comment: Meanwhile, `serverSocket.BeginReceiveFrom(byteData, 0, bufferSize, SocketFlags.None, ref sender, ClientConnected, sender);` try exchanging the last param for `serversocket`.

Comment: it no longer stops at that line, but isnt the last param to pass information to the callback?

Comment: Exactly. And _in_ your callback you get it from `asyncResult.AsyncState`. It threw a NullReferenceException on you before, because what `as Socket` does is: it tries to cast to the type requested and will result in null if it cannot do that. Now before, you got an EndPoint out, which is not a Socket and thus resulted in a NRE.

Comment: yes, that is it... thanks

Comment: Why TPL? what's the difference with what im currently using?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error and I ended up solving it and it was like this

Example: [example on github](https://github.com/AlecioFuranze/HiOps)

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

public class UdpListenZ
{ 
    public List<Socket> connections { get; private set; } = new List<Socket>();
    public IPAddress address { get; private set; } = IPAddress.Any;
    public int port { get; private set; } = 0;
    public IPEndPoint localEndPoint { get; private set; } = new IPEndPoint(0, 0);
    public Socket listen { get; set; } = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
    private byte[] received { get; set; } = new byte[1];
    private EndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    public event EventZ.Connect OnConnect;
    public event EventZ.Receive OnReceive;
    public event EventZ.Disconnect OnDisconnect;

    public void Init(IPAddress address, int port)
    {
        this.address = address;
        this.port = port;
        this.localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(address, port);
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        listen.Bind(localEndPoint);
        ReceiveNow();
    }

    private void ReceiveNow()
    {
        received = new byte[1024 * 4];
        point = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0) as EndPoint;
        listen.BeginReceiveFrom(received, 0, received.Length, SocketFlags.None, ref point, Receive, point);
    }

    private void Receive(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        var point = result.AsyncState as EndPoint;
        var size = listen.EndReceiveFrom(result, ref point);
        var data = new byte[size];
        Array.Copy(received, data, data.Length);

        OnReceive?.Invoke(data, point);

        ReceiveNow();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        listen?.Close();
    
        connections.Clear();

        listen?.Dispose();
    }
}
```